static java reflection - enum of fields of a class (pre-compilation)
is there a type of reflection in Java that provides simply an enum of the fields in a class?
The information is, afterall, "precompilation-static".  Why should it not be compiled into the class?
While I understand the merits of dynamic abilities an approach like a Reflection API enforces on the ecosystem, and indeed a stroke of genius in foresight in culturing an OO mindset, and the momentum of what has become an amazingly flexible JVM...
But. In the spirit of Java 8's -parameters, and recent realization-of-pain in Graal native compilation related to use of the Reflection API, why not provide basic hard-coded  (liiightweight) "reflection" ability as a built in compilation step for SOME* metadata that doesn't interfere with that genius* that should be preserved.
*musing inheritance, and the dynamic spirit of the JVM
*hat-tip to the genius that built the people, industry and ecosystem
The benefits in mapping POJOs/ORM would be enormous.
fwiw, annotation processors COULD have this, but its the opposite direction of the spirit of this question. As it may be, the question might be in the opposite spirit of the genius that built what we have today.  But, I do not think the topic should be muted by the tide here.
Anyways,

Looking to get a set, define a subset of, and filter out some fields from set-of-all (see examples)

and call getters/setters, albiet non-classical, by way of an enumeration to reference the field name/type/modifiers).


e.g.
o.setString(MyClass.Fields.AFIELD, value)


Hear me out... while obvs ICKY from a lot of perspectives, from an ORM perspective, there's like ... 7 types of setters needed.  Where ORM, or http params-to-Java is 80% of the codebase, "theory vs practice", the harsher reality just wins;  Wins today. and there's an understanding of why it didn't win in the past.

any compiler flags to enable this? Plugins to javac?
an alternative javac? I know, boooo.
this isn't a question in the annotation processor headspace, not at all.

Practically, while I'm not a 'language being', and I know there's "reasons"... but as someone simply working on some high up ORM/http mapping stuff... shouldn't this be (added like a decade ago) ?
public class NiceClass {

    //* NOTE this is not real java code today - don't copy and paste expecting it to work! */
    static {

        Set<NiceClass.class.field> allMyFields = NiceClass.class.fieldz.public();
        Set<NiceClass.class.field> allMyLocalPublicFields = NiceClass.class.fieldz.local.public();

        Set<NiceClass.class.field> allMyLocalPrivateAndLocalProtectedFields = { Sets.union(
                                                                NiceClass.class.fieldz.local.private(),
                                                                NiceClass.class.fieldz.local.protected())}

        Set<NiceClass.class.field> specificFields = { Set.of(NiceClass.class.fields.ONE, 
                                                             NiceClass.class.fields.THREE, 
                                                             NiceClass.class.fields.FIVE  )}

        Set<NiceClass.class.field> allFieldsWithoutLoggerByFieldName = { 
            NiceClass.class.fieldz.all().stream().filter(s-> s.name != "logger" ).collect(Collectors.toSet()) }

        Set<NiceClass.class.field> allFieldsWithoutLoggerByType = { 
            NiceClass.class.fieldz.all().stream().filter(s-> s.type != Logger.class ).collect(Collectors.toSet())
        }

        Set<NiceClass.class.field> allNonTransientFields = { 
            NiceClass.class.fieldz.all().stream().filter(s-> s.modifier != Modifier.transient ).collect(Collectors.toSet())
        }

        Set<NiceClass.class.field> holyGrailMySerialization = { 
            allFieldsWithoutLoggerByType.stream().filter(s-> s.access != private && 
                                                             ! Modifiers.contains(Modifier.transient) && 
                                                             ! Modifiers.contains(Modifier.volatile) &&
                                                             s.type != MyCredentials.class )
                                                             .collect(Collectors.toSet())

        }

        Set<NiceClass.class.field> holyGrailMySerialization = { 
            holdGrailMySerialization.stream().filter(s-> ! s.annotations.contains(PrivateStuff.class) )
                                                             .collect(Collectors.toSet())

    }

    //and if you give the mouse a cookie...why shouldn't these be easy to "enable"?

    public void set(Object.FieldInterface fieldEnum, Object value); //(casting in impl) 

    //and typesafe...
    NiceClass.class.fieldz.stream().filter(
            s->s.setterEnabled)
            .map(s->s.type)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()).foreach(s->{
    
                <modifiers> void set<s.type>(fieldEnum, value);
            }
    })

    //bonus to figure out how to reduce that param to what's *statically enabled*...

    //I know this is wonky looking syntax ( a Set of types allowed in a generic? )
    <modifiers> void set<s.type>(Object.FieldInterface<!!Set.contains(NiceClass.class.fieldz.enabled)>) fieldEnum, value);

    //Anyways, the possibilties seem endless having this lightweight reflection...
    
    
}



I'm not sure if this helps, but have you looked at https://projectlombok.org/ ?

Introspector might be what you want.  However, it works on Java Beans properties (whose methods must follow a specific get/set naming pattern), not fields.  This is a good thing—public methods are an object-oriented design, while accessing fields directly very much is not.

You could trivially do this with an annotation processor. Annotate the class you want the fields for, generate a different class containing the data. I recall that some guy on Reddit did that a few months ago: https://github.com/loudsight/entity-meta-generator Is it production-ready and will it generate everything you want? Probably not, but the idea is there. The reddit thread was here: https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/16f3dmx/introducing_an_annotation_processor_for/

Manifold has "type-safe reflection" as well, which is maybe of interest. https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/tree/master/manifold-deps-parent/manifold-ext#type-safe-reflection-via-jailbreak

No.  This isn't present on the JVM, anywhere.  People either use the dynamic approach, or code generation and annotation processing.

@JustanotherJavaprogrammer please see #5

@VGR nope, along with hundreds like it. A simple enum from /what I just wrote into my class file/ is what is where its at.  No annotations, just raw goodness.   AFA Object-orientedness, over my years as a java dev, I'm ok with blurring "setFieldName(String str) with o.setString(Fieldname.MyFieldName, value)" as the second simply avoids any hardship in naming/casing. In So.isManycaSes.  All for the cost of.. wait for it... writing a class file.

You already know you can do Arrays.stream(MyType.class.getDeclaredFields()) (though I still would opt for PropertyDescriptors, myself) and then filter/collect it.  Dynamically creatable enums would defeat the entire purpose of enums—a well known set of values—but you can easily place the fields in a Map by their normalized names, and create a single wrapper class that normalizes string keys before looking them up.  Is that sufficient?

@VGR I've done something similar, although enum-based with superclass.  Generation of an enum was a little further than I had thought, but I suppose, its a two-step compile however it is achieved.

I don’t understand what this question is aiming at. This code will run at runtime, no matter how the field discovery works.

@Holger the aim may be to not use lombok (or for something so simple, so core)?  Anyways, see updated q

@Michael YES! While not as "native" as I was hoping, this is second best. thanks for the link

Nobody is forcing you to use Lombok. If you want to get the fields of a class, you can use ClassName.class.getDeclaredFields(), for example. That’s not using Lombok. As said, yes, it’s happening at runtime, but even when a preprocessor replaces this operation by, let’s say, List.of("foo", "bar", "baz"), the construction of that list still would be happening at runtime anyway.

Turns out there is a Javac Plugin API, which IS an answer to this question.
And making use of it:
As pointed to by @Michael, Manifold framework

... manifolds do not entail build steps, are always in sync, operate incrementally,...

Maybe someday javac will add static access to this metadata, without requiring a javac plugin be used?
Until then, this suffices.
*this is worlds-different from an annotation processor, if you glazed over the words in the quote, take note!

What do you mean with “Maybe someday javac will add this kinda of metadata to .class files?” Javac does store the names of the fields in the class file. And Reflection is the API to extract that information.

Your edit still doesn’t clarify what kind of feature you expect. Your can get a list of all fields with “ClassName.class.getDeclaredFields()”. How simple can someone expect things to become?

OP author here, Just stopping by
Here's a widely-used static metamodel
JPA's Static Metamodel spec. Here's some implementations (though only annotation based)
Note,

not javac Plugin <- alleviates the problem
not javac  <- imagine

but the idea is there!
Concrete
As summarized by this article

Why the JPA Metamodel?
Often, when we write a criteria query, we need to reference entity classes and their attributes.
Now, one of the ways of doing this is to provide the attributes’ names as strings. But, this has several downsides.
For one, we have to look up the names of entity attributes. And, in case a column name is changed later in the project lifecycle, we have to refactor each query where the name is being used.

Illustrated by datanucleus docs
The unfortunate
Path nameField = candidateRoot.get("name");
crit.select(nameField);


which equates to

SELECT p.name


The above accessed a field by its name (as a String). We could easily have accessed it via the Static MetaModel too, like this

Path nameField = candidateRoot.get(Person_.name);
crit.select(nameField);

